# Как скопировать строку после символа ':'

Tags: c, строки, подстрока

Например, есть строка:

```
const char* fullStr = "ddt:magic:id99";
```

Как скопировать в другую строку подстроку после `:`

```
const char* name = strdup(РЕЗУЛЬТАТ); // name = "id99";
```

Пока не знаю даже куда копать...

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да в одну строку! :)

После последнего двоеточия, как я понимаю?

```
const char* name = strdup(strrchr(fullStr,':')+1);
```

Если после первого,

```
const char* name = strdup(strchr(fullStr,':')+1);
```

Проверка, что в строке есть двоеточие, опущена... Думаю, вы ее легко напишете.

Comment: второй пример скопирует "все после первого двоеточия".

Comment: @KoVadim А я где-то писал иное? В задании "скопировать строку после символа ':'", а не "между двоеточиями"...

Comment: я просто уточнил. я не нападал:)

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите на такой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    const char* fullStr = "ddt:magic:id99";
    const char* x1 = strchr(fullStr, ':');
    if (x1 == NULL) { puts("oops"); return 0;}
    x1++;
    const char* x2 = strchr(x1, ':');
    if (x2 == NULL) { puts("oops"); return 0;}
    // посчитаем длину
    long len = x2 - x1;
    // выведем информацию о этом
    printf("%ld .. %ld, len = %ld\n", x1-fullStr, x2-fullStr, len);
    // а тут классика - выделяем память и копируем. размер известен
    char* name = malloc(len+1);
    strncpy(name, x1, len);
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

если строка не константная, то можно использовать strtok.

Comment: только op'у, если верить его примеру, нужна строка после последнего двоеточиего… так что можно и просто: `strdup(strrchr(fullStr, ':'))`

Comment: а, ну это такое дело, я просто прочитал "другую строку" как "вторую строку"

Comment: @Fat-Zer согласен, здесь ошибка strrchr нужен. Но так как вы описали делать нельзя, т.к. нет проверок на пустоту

Comment: @SlimRG, да, согласен…

Comment: @KoVadim исправьте ошибку, вы прибавляете 1 к результату в `x1`, `x2`, и потом проверяете на `NULL`. Т.е. выражение всегда отрицательное.

Comment: да, так бывает, когда условие добавляешь постфактум:)

Answer (score 0):

[`strtok`](http://cppstudio.com/post/747/) должна вам помочь. Она как раз возвращает указатель на последнюю найденную в строке лексему.

```
#include <string.h>
const char * name = strdup(fullStr);
strtok(name, ":");
```

Comment: Это не будет работать, если Вы знаете, как устроена strtok

Comment: @KoVadim Я просто помню, что ей пользовался, когда программировал на С.

Comment: для тех, кто не знает - strtok **модифицирует** переданную ей строку, заменяя разделитель на нулевой символ и возвращает указатели на начало подстроки.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за разъяснения

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде так должно работать? Надо бы вспомнить С.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH `const char * name = fullStr;` тут строка не копируется. просто указатель. strdup нужен. Но это не всегда бывает возможно.